# Magento Admin Ajax request to mysql db

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, ajax

I'm pretty new to magento, so I've been in the process of adding a custom text box in the admin panel that has to query the mysql db to retrieve a specific value.

So I'm thinking that ajax would pretty much do the job with that, however for some reason when i do the ajax call, and step through the code using the debugger,
i notice that the value being sent through never shows up in the function of the block class.

phtml code:

```
new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->ajaxCheck(); ?>', {
    method:'get',
    parameters:{test_attrib:val},
    onSuccess: function(transport){
        retval = transport.responseText;
   }
});
```

Block class code:

```
public function ajaxCheck()
{
    try {
        $tval = $this->getRequest()->getParam("test_attrib");

        if (empty($tval)) {
            Mage::throwException($this->__('Invalid val('.$tval.'). Please check & resubmit.'));
        }
        ....do something with $tval.
        print_r($tval);
    }catch(Exception $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
    } 
}
```

If anyone could help with this please.

---

Thanks for the quick reply guys!

@Raphael at Digital Pianism

As you advised, I made the following changes:

Controller:

```
class Ctest_Mydev_AjaxControl extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 {
public function AjaxAction(){

    $tval = $this->getRequest()->getParam("test_attrib");

      ..do something with tval.

    $result['retval'] = $tval;
      $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}}
```

in phtml file function:

```
  var url = '<? echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('ctest/mydev/ajaxcontrol/AjaxAction'); ?>';

 new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method:'get',
           parameters:{test_attrib:val},
           onSuccess: function(transport){

        var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
        retval = response.retval;
           }
        });
```

like I've mentioned in the comment,when I run it through the debugger, I notice that a key value is assigned at the end of the url: ctest/mydev/ajaxcontrol/AjaxAction

and after that nothing appears to happen.
I'm am unsure what it is that I could be missing

Comment: You need to create controller for that.It will not work in block class

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem here is you're trying to call an URL that matches a block function.

What you need to do:

- Declared a controller first
- Create the `ajaxAction` method in your controller
- Use `$this->getUrl('frontname/controller/action');` to call your controller action in your JS

In your controller you can then return the result by doing

```
$result['retval'] = $tval;
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

And in your JS you can retrieve the value:

```
var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
retval = response.retval;
```

Comment: alright i did that, and it seems to assign a key value to the url, however, it seems to do nothing afterwards. When i try to access that url directly through the browser, i get a 404

Comment: @u_jansen see my edited answer ;)

Comment: I edited my initial question